# Get the Integer value of an enumeration which is a generic

Tags: vb.net, generics, enums

Here is the basic situation.

```
Public Class MyEnumClass(of T)
   Public MyValue as T
End Class
```

This is vast oversimplification of the actual class, but basically I know that T is an enumeration (if it is not then there will be many other problems, and is a logical error made by the programmer)

Basically I want to get the underlying integer value of MyValue.

Using Cint or Ctype, does not work.

Comment: I completely mis-read enumeration as IEnumerable :(

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I was going to use a cool piece of reflection code but just a simple [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx) works great...  Forgive my VB I'm a C# guy

```
Public Function GetEnumInt(Of T)(enumVal As T) As Integer
    Return Convert.ToInt32(enumVal)
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

I tried this and it worked:

```
String.Format("{0:d}", MyValue)
```

Comment: Well that converts it into a *string* - I thought you wanted it as an integer?

Answer (score 4):

I know you can do the following to get all the underlying values (I hope my VB syntax is correct... I've been working in C# mostly of late):

```
Dim intVal As Integer

For Each intVal In  [Enum].GetValues(GetType(T))
    //intValue is now the enum integer value
Next
```

That might at least get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

This also works : 
`Fix(enumval)`

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way in VB.NET is to add it to 0:

```
Dim intVal As Integer = 0 + myEnum
```

So, this should work:

```
Sub GetEnumInt(of T)(enumVal as T) as Int
   return 0 + enumVal
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work when `myEnum` is of a generic type parameter type, because the compiler doesn't know whether it is actually an enum, and will therefore not typecheck operator `+`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to 'Jon Skeet'. But his code does not work in my Excel-2016. Minwhile the next code works fine:

```
Public Enum TypOfProtectWs
    pws_NotFound = 0
    pws_AllowAll = 1
    pws_AllowFormat = 2
    pws_AllowNone = 3
End Enum

Private Function TypOfProtectWs2I(pws As TypOfProtectWs) As Integer
    TypOfProtectWs2I = Format("0", pws)
End Function

Private Sub test_TypOfProtectWs2I()
    Debug.Print TypOfProtectWs2I(pws_AllowAll)
End Sub
```