# VB.NET - Webservice return ENUM Index instead of value

Tags: vb.net, web-services, serialization, enums

I'm facing a problem returning the value of an ENUM in a method from my Webservice.

I have this enum in Webservice:

```
<DataContract(Name:="EGenre")> _
Public Enum EGenre
    <EnumMember()> Action = 15  'Index 0
    <EnumMember()> Fiction = 58 'Index 1
    <EnumMember()> Horror = 33  'Index 2
End Enum
```

And this method (sample only):

```
Public Function ReturnGenreFiction () As EGenre
    Return EGenre.Fiction
End Function
```

And in my application i have this:

```
....
Dim myWs As New WSMovies
...
Dim idx = myWs.ReturnGenreFiction()
```

But the return that does not have the value attributed to ENUM, but the position (index) of the property.

For example:

*"The value I get in the "idx" variable is 1 instead of 58"*

I thought it was something related to serialization, but apparently it's not synonymous... What could be happening?

*Obs.: I'm consuming this Webservice through an "ActiveX form".*

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It starts at `0` that is why... Have you seen [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378801/get-the-integer-value-of-an-enumeration-which-is-a-generic). Or you can try this `CType([Enum].GetValues(GetType(EGenre)), Integer())`. This returns an array of integers, you can get what you want out of it then.

Comment: @Zaggler This does not change anything, I just put here an example.

Comment: If you split the statement in two lines in 'ReturnGenreFiction': Dim value As Integer = EGenre.Fiction : Return value'. What is the value then?

Comment: @Ruard van Elburg!  On Webservice i have 58 (ReturnGenreFiction() Return 58), but on application i have "1" (myWs.ReturnGenreFiction()  = 1).